# How to get mouse coordinates between two points in a picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Can anyone help me on this?

I have a picture box with a image and this image have some coordinates.
My X starts at 60 and end at 135
My Y stats at 75 and end at 120

Because i have only the first and the last point, i want to calculate and see the coordinates when i mouse over my image.

I started with solving my first problem: i have to delimitate my start and my end.
So i tried a trackbar.

Im trying first get the current X position:

Set my picturebox at position x = 0;

Set my trackbar at position x = -10, so my first pin will be at position 0;

Set my tracbar size.x = picturebox.x + 20, so my last pin will be at end of picture box.

My trackbar have the current properties: 
Minimum = 60, Maximum = 135;

Set a mouse move event in my picturebox:

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        double dblValue;
        dblValue = ((double)e.X/ (double)trackBar1.Width) * (trackBar1.Maximum - trackBar1.Minimum);
        dblValue = dblValue + 60;
        trackBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dblValue);
        lblX.Text = dblValue.ToString();
    }
```

It's almost working, but still not very accurate.
Anyone have some idea that may work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what it is you are trying to do, but if you are trying to get to the coordinates within the picturebox, there is a function on the pictureBox class called `PointToClient(Point)` that computes the location of the specified screen point into client coordinates.  You can use the X and Y coordinates from the `MouseEventArgs` to create the `Point` object to pass to the function.

To clarify:

The `X` and `Y` properties of the `MouseEventArgs` in the `MouseMove` event are the screen coordinates (0,0) being the upper left corner of the screen.

Many controls like the `PictureBox` control include a `PointToClient` method that will convert the screen coordinates to the local control's coordinates, where (0,0) will be the upper left corner of the control.

So, for example, if your control is placed on the screen at location (60, 75) and has a bottom right coordinate of (135, 120).  If your mouse is over the control, and is 10 pixels from the left and 20 pixels from the top, then the `X` and `Y` properties of the MouseEventArgs in the MouseMove event would be: `X` = 70 and `Y` = 95.  If you convert these to the internal coordinates of the picturebox control using `PointToClient`, it will indicate that `X` = 10 and `Y` = 20.

Now, if you were wanting to have a `TrackBar` that displays a relative indication of where the X coordinate of the mouse is over some control, you would calculate it as follows:

```
// Set the minimum and maximum of the trackbar to 0 and 100 for a simple percentage.
trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
trackBar1.Maximum = 100;

// In the pictureBox1_MouseMove event have the following code:
trackBar1.Value = pictureBox1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).X * 100 / pictureBox1.Width;
```

If you wanted to have the trackbar use screen coordinates to track the relative position of the X coordinate of the mouse over some control, you would calculate it as follows:

```
// Set the minimum and maximum values of the track bar to the screen coordinates of the 
// control we want to track.
trackBar1.Minimum = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(0,0).X;
trackBar1.Maximum = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Width, 0).X;

// In the pictureBox1_MouseMove event have the following code:
trackBar1.Value = e.X;
```

If you wanted to have the trackbar use the internal coordinates of some control to track the internal position of the X coordinate of the mouse over that control, you would calculate it as follows:

```
// Set the minimum and maximum values of the track bar to zero and the width of the
// control we want to track.
trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
trackBar1.Maximum = pictureBox1.Width;

// In the pictureBox1_MouseMove event have the following code:
trackBar1.Value = pictureBox1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).X;
// or - not recommended - read below.
trackBar1.Value = e.X - pictureBox1.Left;
```

Now, there is one caveat, and that is if you put controls inside other controls, like a panel inside a panel inside a panel, etc. then the 'world' coordinates of a control inside of another control are based upon their location within the parent control.  That is why it is a good idea to use the internal coordinates of the control via `PointToClient` and screen coordinates from internal coordinates via `PointToScreen` because otherwise you would have to work your way up through all of the containers until you reached the screen, keeping track of `Top` and `Left` coordinates all the way.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: PointToClient will calculate 0 to X. I want to give the first and the last coordinates, and calculate the between. My image dont start at x = 0, but x = 60;

Comment: Then wouldn't that just be the window coordinates?  I'll edit my answer to clarify, and maybe it will answer your question.